# Chrome Dev Tools console logs [ f ] instead of the values of the array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to JavaScript and Stack Overflow (taking a JavaScript Udemy course at the moment).
While doing an assignment on arrays, I noticed the Chrome Dev console only outputs *[f, f, f, f]* and the entire percentages array instead of the values I hoped it would output. Here's my code:

```
//function that converts a population into a percent of the world population
function percentageOfWorld1 (population) {
    ((population / 7900) * 100);
    return percentageOfWorld1;
}
//array of different populations (in millions)
const populations = [331.9, 1458, 1380, 147.2];

//checks if there are 4 array elements
console.log(populations.length === 4);

//converts each element in the array to a percentage from the function
const percentages = [
    percentageOfWorld1(populations[0]),
    percentageOfWorld1(populations[1]),
    percentageOfWorld1(populations[2]),
    percentageOfWorld1(populations[3])
];
//logs the array
console.log(percentages);
```

And this is what the console on Chrome Dev outputs:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B21dg.jpg)

I'm a little confused why it only logs *[f, f, f, f]* instead of an array of numbers.

I tried searching around and couldn't really find something that helped me. Also tried changing the variables around a little bit, but it still didn't change the console output. The console.log that checks if there are 4 array elements returns the expected value, though.

Comment: The console collapses nested values - you can inspect each of the entries within the array by clicking on the little triangle. In this case, it's only displaying the function itself because `percentageOfWorld1` is incorrectly implemented - change the first line to `return ((population / 7900) * 100)`

Answer (score 0):

`((population / 7900) * 100)` does nothing because result of that calculation is not assigned to any variable.
And the function returns itself instead, so, what you see is array of `percentageOfWorld1` functions.

What you probably meant to do is return the result of the calculation:

```
function percentageOfWorld1 (population) {
    return ((population / 7900) * 100);
}
```